# how can I count all possibilities with 4 letters minus 1, then 2, then 3?

Tags: combinatorics

I don't remember how to call what I try to do, I even don't remember how to compute that. I have 4 letters, A, B, C, D. I want to compute all possibilities if I removed one letter :

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline A& B & C & \\
\hline A& B& &D\\ 
\hline A& & C&D\\ 
\hline & B& C&D\\ 
\hline\end{array}

then I want to compute all possibilities if I remove 2 letters, for example if I shutdown the last column :

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline A& B &  & \\
\hline A& & C& \\ 
\hline & B& C& \\ 
\hline\end{array}

then I want to compute for 3 letters and finally I want to sum all the possibilities. In my case I don't think permutation is important, but for the sake of my brain if someone can show me how to compute that without permutation and with permutation, thank you.

Comment: In your second case, it looks like you're either choosing two letters to keep or two to discard, so it's "four choose two", written ${4 \choose 2}$, which is $\frac{4!}{(4-2)!2!} = \frac{24}{2\times 2}=6$

Comment: @Joffan thx, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Joffan could you just tell me the name of this formula ?

Comment: these are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), very useful to know about and understand

Comment: @Joffan thank you, may the metal gods be with you \m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read correctly that you want to find then number of groups of 3, 2, and 1 letters from A,B,C,D...

Each of the letters can be present or not present.  So in this case there are $2*2*2*2=2^4$ possibilities.  You can subtract out one or two if you don't want to include the case of all letters/no letters or both.  So in this case $16-2=14$

Comment: your explanation is good, however I expected the formula that Joffan wrote. Thank you.